# Android: How to check whether findElementById returns null in Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In the  Code below I am accessing the element 'search-field' via
findElementById. But I instead of setting a value would like to ckeck whether  findElementById
returns null, like in Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById('search field')==null).
```

How can I do that here?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

     WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
     String url = "https://www.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/";
     wb.loadUrl(url);

     wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     wb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               String s = "tea";
               String js = "javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('search-field').value = '"+s+"';})();";
               view.loadUrl(js); 
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the evaluateJavascript function:

```
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String js2 = "var isNull = document.getElementById('search-field') == null; isNull;";
            view.evaluateJavascript(js2, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                    Log.d("WebViewClient", "onReceiveValue(" + value + ")");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

It will return a String value of the javascript response, in this example "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this using jsoup. This could be a good read : “Getting Started with JSOUP in Android” by Damilola Omoyiwola https://link.medium.com/gRCrINRNt1

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the String variable js is null or empty:

```
if (js.equals(null) || js.isEmpty()) {
   // do stuff when it's null or an empty string ...
}
```